# Django Search Functionality gives error Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains

Tags: django

I am getting a strange error in my search functionality:

```
def search(request):
    query=request.GET['query']
    messages = {}
    if len(query)>78:
        allPosts=Post.objects.none()
    else:
        allPostsTitle= Post.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)
        allPostsAuthor= Post.objects.filter(author__icontains=query)
        allPostsContent =Post.objects.filter(content__icontains=query)
        allPosts=  allPostsTitle.union(allPostsContent, allPostsAuthor)
    if allPosts.count()==0:
        messages.warning(request, "No search results found. Please refine your query.")    
    params={'allPosts': allPosts, 'query': query}    
    return render(request, 'blog/search.html', params)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
    youtubeVideo = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE, max_length=200, null=True,blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images',null=True,blank=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='blogpost_like', blank=True, null=True)
    

    def number_of_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programming\NewProjecttoReviseAllTechnologies\Django Blog\djangoNewEnv\django\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\Programming\NewProjecttoReviseAllTechnologies\Django Blog\djangoNewEnv\django\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\Programming\NewProjecttoReviseAllTechnologies\Django Blog\djangoNewEnv\django\mysite\blog\views.py", line 269, in search
    allPostsAuthor= Post.objects.filter(author__icontains=query)
  File "D:\Programming\NewProjecttoReviseAllTechnologies\Django Blog\djangoNewEnv\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Programming\NewProjecttoReviseAllTechnologies\Django Blog\djangoNewEnv\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 941, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, args, kwargs)
  File "D:\Programming\NewProjecttoReviseAllTechnologies\Django Blog\djangoNewEnv\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 961, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, args, kwargs)
  File "D:\Programming\NewProjecttoReviseAllTechnologies\Django Blog\djangoNewEnv\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 968, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "D:\Programming\NewProjecttoReviseAllTechnologies\Django Blog\djangoNewEnv\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1396, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "D:\Programming\NewProjecttoReviseAllTechnologies\Django Blog\djangoNewEnv\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1415, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "D:\Programming\NewProjecttoReviseAllTechnologies\Django Blog\djangoNewEnv\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1350, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "D:\Programming\NewProjecttoReviseAllTechnologies\Django Blog\djangoNewEnv\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1187, in build_lookup
    raise FieldError('Related Field got invalid lookup: {}'.format(lookup_name))
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains
```

Comment: can you share your models and full error traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are using `icontains` with the author which is a *fk* so try changing your query like this.

```
Post.objects.filter(author__username__icontains=query)
```

Comment: I found the answer on the internet prior to your answer. Still you gave the right answer